# Updating the whole page with an Ajax.ActionLink

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

Is it possible to have an Ajax.ActionLink(...,...) to refresh the whole page instead of an UpdatetargetID?

I prefer using an Ajax.ActionLink because the classic Html.ActionLink is not a POST method.

I try:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Click me", "MyAction", "MyController", new { value = '1234' }, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", Confirm = "Are you sure ?" },  null)
```

But the page is not refreshed, I had to press F5.

Thanks.

Comment: just curious, what's wrong with GET method?

Comment: This is not a good idea using a GET method for performing tasks such as changing state of things in an application (deleting records, changing satus, ...). Here I need an actionLink for changing status that's why I don't want to use a classic html.actionlink who perform a GET.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can actually combine the two methods proposed by gardarvalur to get MVC-like code that doesn't require wrapping the entire page in a div.  Move window.location.reload() call to the OnSuccess property of the AjaxOptions object like this:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Click me", "MyAction", "MyController", new { value = '1234' }, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", OnSuccess="window.location.reload()" })
```

No jQuery involved, just some plain old javascript in an MVC Ajax ActionLink.

Comment: Had to use window.location.href = window.location.href; to avoid the repost warning

Answer (score 2):

What about doin ajax call within Jquery?  Something like this.

```
<button onclick="SomeFunction()" type="button" >Click me</button>
```

And then in Jquery something like this:

```
function SomeFunction()
{
    var url = '/MyController/MyAction/';

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: { value: '1234' }, //if there are any parameters
        dataType: "html", //or some other type
        success: function (data) {
            window.location.reload(true);
            // or something in that area, maybe with the 'data'
        },
        error: function () {
        //some derp
        }
    });
```

I hope I´m not misunderstanding your question (and I realize this is not exactly using ajax.actionlink).  ;)
Regards!

**########## EDITED #########**

Or maybe a far fetched idea, telling the link to updatetargetid that wraps your whole page in.  Something like this:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Click me", "MyAction", "MyController", new { value = '1234' }, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", Confirm = "Are you sure ?", UpdateTargetId = "TheDivToUpdate" },  null)
```

And then wrap the content of your page with this div tag:

```
<div id="TheDivToUpdate">
    //The content of your page
</div>
```

I know, not the most beautiful solution but maybe it works for you?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but I don't want to use jQuery this time. I prefer a more 'MVC' like solution.

Comment: aaa ok, I edited my answer, just in case if that would work instead :)

Comment: Using reload, I get the following msg box "to display the webpage again the web browser needs to resend the information you've previously"